# Vue JS - Conditionally show the information in one component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that reactively displays the data contained in an array of objects. At the moment, the component displays both objects, but I would like it to display one based on a condition. How can I have one or the other object displayed based on the state of a property named premiumActivated?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="background-div">
      <div class="page-info-inner">
          <PremiumContent v-for="item in premiumContent"
                          :key="item.infoText" 
                          :info-text="item.infoText" 
                          :button-text="item.buttonText"
                          :button-callback="null"
                          :subscription-text="item.subscriptionText" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import PremiumContent from '../../../components/partials/settings/Premium';
  
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    components: {PremiumContent},
    data: () => ({
      premiumActivated: false,
      premiumContent: [
        { 
          infoText: "this is the content that should appear if premiumActivated is false",
          buttonText: "button text",
        },
        { 
          infoText: "this is the content that should appear if premiumActivated is true",
          buttonText: "button text",
          subscriptionText: 'extra text',
        },
      ]
    }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of computed property in Vue to decide which object from the array needs to display.

```
computed: {
    displayContent () {
        return this.premiumActivated ? premiumContent[1] : premiumContent[0]
    }
}
```

Your PremiumContent will look like this:

```
<PremiumContent
                          :key="displayContent.infoText" 
                          :info-text="displayContent.infoText" 
                          :button-text="displayContemt.buttonText"
                          :button-callback="null"
                          :subscription-text="displayContent.subscriptionText" />
```

EDIT:
Another solution can be to make use of `computed` or `mounted` hook.

```
computed () {
    this.item = this.premiumActivated ? premiumContent[1] : premiumContent[0]
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic in all this, but don't computed properties always expect a return value?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I forgot to add the return to the computed property.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to clarify that. However, I still keep getting an eslint error stating "Unexpected side effect in "displayContent" computed property."

Comment: Ya, the issue is because we are updating the data object in the computed property. I think the solution for this may be using `created` or `mounted` hook or directly using the computed property in template.